# Jackson JsonSerializer

Tags: spring-mvc, java-8, jackson, jackson-databind

I have simple serializer with Jaskcon

```
public class NullSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {

    public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeString("");
    }
}
```

After Compiling this code Java throws Error

```
Error:java: java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

I am using this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Works perfectly well for me:

```
public class Main {
  static class NullSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {

    public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeString("");
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addSerializer(Object.class, new NullSerializer());
    m.registerModule(module);
    System.out.println(m.writeValueAsString(
        Arrays.asList(true, 1, "String", new HashMap())
    )); //prints "", while without registerModule - [true,1,"String",{}]
  }
}
```

I would look somewhere else.

For one, check your Xss for Maven. Should be at least `-Xss256k`, maybe you will need more, or even better, leave it default at 1MB, because compiler uses stack differently than Java and sometimes puts structures on the stack.

I hope you are not using GWT, because if your code got exposed to GWT compiler, it would be a typical response in this situation.

And the least likely event would be that you found a genuine bug in the compiler.

Try using `--debug` option with Maven, maybe it will show more info.